# Are convex functions measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex function.

Then, is $f$ Borel-measurable?

From basic analysis, I know that $f$ is measurable (moreover, continuous) if $n=1$.

However, I am curious if this is still measurable if $n>1$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes; convex functions on finite-dimensional spaces are continuous on the interior of their domain, hence they are Borel-measurable when defined over the entire space.

Comment: Where can I find this proof?

Comment: To the  proposer: First try  a proof by contradiction with $n=1$: Suppose  for example that $\lim_{y\to 0^+}\inf\; \{f(z):z\in (x-y,x)\}\ne f(x).$

Comment: @Rubertos See Corollary 10.1.1  (p.83) of Rockafellar's "Convex Analysis".

Comment: @Rubertos Alternatively, there's Theorem 2.1.12, p.25, in *Convex Functions: Constructions, Characterizations and Counterexamples* by Jonathan M. Borwein and Jon D. Vanderwerff. For an infinite-dimensional version, there's Proposition 4.1.5 on p. 129; however, an assumption of lower semi-continuity is necessary.